# Covariant derivative of a composite field and the chain rule

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, differentiation

I have a gauge theory with some rather strange covariant derivatives and I am wondering how they act on a composite field like $\psi= \phi\psi'$. In my setup, the covariant derivative acting on a scalar and on a fermion are defined as follows.

$$ D_\mu\phi = (\partial_\mu - \frac{1}{2}\kappa_\mu)\phi \quad , \quad D_\mu\psi = (\partial_\mu + \Gamma_\mu)\psi $$

I have made the field redefinition $\psi= \phi\psi'$ and I am wondering how the covariant derivative behaves in my fermion kinetic term $i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi$. Should we expand the derivative before we do the chain rule, or after? Explicitly, which of the following is correct?

(i) $D_\mu\psi = (\partial_\mu + \Gamma_\mu)\psi = (\partial_\mu + \Gamma_\mu)\phi\psi' = \phi\partial_\mu\psi' + \psi'\partial_\mu\phi + \Gamma_\mu\phi\psi'$

(ii) $D_\mu\psi = D_\mu(\phi\psi') = \phi(D_\mu\psi') + \psi'(D_\mu\phi) = \phi(\partial_\mu + \Gamma_\mu)\psi' + \psi'(\partial_\mu - \frac{1}{2}\kappa_\mu)\phi $

It seems that (ii) is correct if $D_\mu$ is truly a derivative in the sense of basic calculus, but I can also see why (i) might be right. I won't go into my hand-wavy reasoning here - is there a formal way to see which is correct?

Comment: check the transformation properties of the kinetic term you quote under gauge transformations. presumably only one of the two choices (if either of the two) will be gauge invariant.

Comment: @Wakabaloola I don't think either choice is invariant. I am left with $i\phi^{-1/2}\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu D_\mu\psi$ after a conformal transformation and I defined $\psi'$ in order to canonically normalize my fermion kinetic term.

Comment: hmm. i'm not sure. you might need to let the connection transform as well under your field redefinition, such that gauge invariance remains intact. (Incidentally, why are conformal transformations relevant here?)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly The scalar is charged with respect to $\kappa_\mu$, but the fermion is not. May I ask which of the following two options you think is correct? Let's say I want to calculate $D_\mu(\phi^2)$.     (i) $D_\mu(\phi^2) = (\partial_\mu -\frac{1}{2}\kappa_\mu)(\phi^2) = 2\phi\partial_\mu\phi -\frac{1}{2}\kappa_\mu\phi^2$     (ii)$D_\mu(\phi^2) = 2\phi(D_\mu\phi) = 2\phi\partial\phi - \kappa_\mu\phi^2$          The difference in this case is just a factor of 2 on the last term, but it essentially the same question.

Comment: @Wakabaloola I have already taken the connection into account here. Apologies for the vague nature of the following, but this is part of a paper I am working on involving Weyl geometric gravity coupled to fermions. $\kappa_\mu$ is the Weyl gauge field and the conformal transformation is done in order to go to unitary gauge. There are a bunch of other terms in my Lagrangian that would make this more clear, but I don't want to put the whole thing on here. Please see my last comment to ChiralAnomaly where I put forward a toy model of my question. What would you say is correct in that case?

Comment: (i) is correct. In (ii), the effect of the covariant derivative on the primed spinor will be different: it will involve kappa. It must, because the charge of psi must equal the charge of phi times psi-prime. (Sorry.. lost my backslash key.)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Ok great, thanks - accounting for the charge makes sense. Just out of curiosity, how would you argue for either of the two options in the toy model in my previous comment? The charge is not an issue there, but I still get two different results.

Comment: Sorry, the numbers in my previous comment referred to the original post. In the scalar-only model in your comment, (ii) is correct. The squared field has twice the charge of the original, and accounting for this fixes the (i) in your comment.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I see. Thanks again!

Comment: this question is still confusing me. first of all, it seems inconsistent to me to use the same symbol for both connections, since they really are different.  i think the safest bet is to work in terms of components.  if you want the field redefinition to preserve gauge invariance, maybe you could check if there is a natural connection that arises by demanding that whatever it is gauge invariance remains intact.